Find the transformation of $\iint y^2$ inside $y=x, y=2x, xy=2, xy=4$
I am stumped on this math problem.
Find an appropriate change of variables u=u(x,y), v=(x,y) of
$$
 \iint_r y^2 dA
$$
when A is given by
$$
y =x, y=2x, xy=2, xy=4
$$
My current attempts start well but crashes quite fast.
If we let $ u = \frac{y}{x}$, and let $ v = xy$, we can see that the bounds turn out quite nicely too $0\le\frac{y}{x}\le2$ and $2\le xy \le4$
Furthermore, $u(v) = \frac{y}{x}(xy)$ giving $ uv=y^2$, or $\sqrt{uv} = y$.
However, that's about as far as I can go. I can't find an ice way to define x in terms of $u$ and $v$. If I can get a nudge in the right direction, I would be rather grateful. Thank you in advanced math wizards.

Ummm, your double integral expression seems to be missing something.

Oh shoot, you're totally right. Sorry have too much time in the library today haha.

Why do you need to find $x$ in terms of $u,v$ ? Just calculate the inverse Jacobian as is with $u,v$ as functions of $x,y$. Then there is an extremely simple relationship between the inverse Jacobian and the Jacobian you want. There are many examples on this site that go through this process.

Shouldn't you have $1\leq\frac{y}{x}\leq 2$ ?

Don't you mean that $A$ is the area delimited by the lines y=x,y=2x,xy=2,xy=4. Because as stated $A$ is $y=x,y=2x,xy=2,xy=4$ would imply that $A$ is the empty set.

Yes to both. Turns out the math test that I took this morning didn't even ask a question about Jacobians. I am going to take some time now (with less stress) to truly understand whats being asked, instead of trying to memorize applications from the preetst.


If we let $u=yx$, and let $v=xy$, we can see that the bounds turn out quite nicely too $0≤y/x≤2$ and $2≤xy≤4$

That is $\color{red} 1\leq u\leq 2$ and $2\leq v\leq 4$

Furthermore, $uv=(y/x)(xy)$ giving $uv=y^2$, or $\sqrt{uv~}=y$

Well, similarly $v/u= x^2$ so
$$\begin{align}\iint_R y^2\,\mathrm d A &=\int_1^2\!\!\int_2^4 uv\,\begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial (\sqrt{v/u}, \sqrt{uv})}{\partial (u,v)}\end{Vmatrix}\,\mathrm d v\,\mathrm d u\end{align}$$
Alternatively, you could use the inverse Jacobian theorem.
$$\dfrac{\partial (\sqrt{v/u}, \sqrt{uv})}{\partial (u,v)}=\left.\dfrac{\partial (y/x, xy)}{\partial (x,y)}\right\rvert_{\raise{2ex}{x=\surd(v/u)\\ y=\surd(uv)}}^{-1}$$
